# searchform.php :: pass second query string variable with same value as ?s=

Tags: search

I want to pass an additional parameter in my search URLs that would match the search term, but using an additional variable named 'x'. So, when performing a search, the user would enter "Cars" and the URL would be http://example.com?s=cars&x=cars.

Is this pretty easy to do? I've tried using:

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" onfocus'if (this.value == "<?php the_search_query();?> ") { this.value = ""; }' onblur='if (this.value == "") { this.value = "<?php the_search_query();?>"; } ' />

<input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" value="<?php the_search_query(); " />
```

However, this doesn't output both variables as $_GET params. In fact it alternates.

So, using this method, I search for cars and I get http://example.com?s=cars&x=

Then if I search for "trucks" next, I get http://example.com?s=trucks&x=cars

So, the current method is informed by the previous search - not desired.

How can I output (safely? wordpressily?) both ?s= and &x= the exact same values, every search?

Comment: I wonder why you need an extra GET parameter with the same value. Maybe you could solve the "main" problem in another way?

Comment: I don't want to affect Wordpress' underlying search system - which I read on here is a bad idea - I want to be able to pass the same value to an external API that requires 'x'.

However, if I can change Wordpress' 's' query string parameter, and that's simple, I'm more than willing.

Comment: If this is some PHP API, what about `$x = get_query_var( 's' );` or `$x = apply_filters( 'get_search_query', get_query_var( 's' ) );`?

Comment: It's not, it REST